# How to configure / Install xmpp server on xp

Tags: xmpp

I want to configure XMPP server on my machine (Microsoft Windows xp professional), Please tell me how can I proceed. Where can i download it from and what all are the steps for intallation.

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: They provide an Installer for that.Just like you install any other thing.

Comment: I googled and downloaded [like from ejabberd and others] the many installers but could not install, if u know some link where I can find some step by step installation guide then please let me know.

Comment: @techie_28 He's asking about XMPP (jabber), not XAMPP!

Comment: @veljkoz LOL! Sorry...

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to install an XMPP/Jabber server on Windows XP is to install [Openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/index.jsp). Here is the [guide](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/install-guide.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is an ejabberd installer for Windows here:
http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/downloads/

Does it works for you on Windows XP ?

Comment: Here is the [direct link to the binary](http://www.process-one.net/downloads/ejabberd/2.1.11/ejabberd-2.1.11-windows-installer.exe)